# Entity Framework Core SQLite con Xamarin.Forms no actualiza Db

Tags: c#, entity-framework, xamarin.forms

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en Xamarin.Forms MVVM con Entity Framework Core SQLite en la cual salvo la Db local mente en el teléfono movil.

Genero la Db y le añado algunos elementos por defecto, despues atarves de la App genero nuevoes elementos los cuales se salvan en la Db y se muestran una la ListView sin ningun tipo de problema.

El problema esta en cuando quiero actualizar un elemento de la Db. Actualizo el elemento atraves de la App pero no se me refresca la ListView con el elemento actualizado. La única forma de que me aparece la modificiaicon en la ListView es reiniciando la aplicacion.

**¿Como puedo refrescar la LIstView para que me muestre el elemento modificado sin tener que cerrar y volver a abrir la aplicaiocn?**

## Este es el Datacontext:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext() : base()
    {
        //Database.EnsureDeleted();
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    public DbSet<Sensor> Sensors { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename={Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "database.sqlite")}");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Sensor>(s =>
        {
            s.HasKey(en => en.Id);
            //s.HasIndex(en => en.ClientId).IsUnique();
            s.Property(en => en.Name).IsRequired();
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Sensor>()
            .HasData(
                new Sensor { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), ClientId = "11111", Name = "First item", Description = "This is a private item description.", Payload = "Off" },
                new Sensor { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), ClientId = "11112", Name = "Second item", Description = "This is a shopping item description.", Payload = "Off" },
                new Sensor { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), ClientId = "11113", Name = "Third item", Description = "This is a work item description.", Payload = "Off" }
            );
    }
```

## Este es el MainPageViewModel:

```
    public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;
    private readonly DataContext _dataContext;
    private static MainPageViewModel _instance;
    private DelegateCommand _addSensorCommand;
    private List<SensorItemViewModel> _sensors;

    public MainPageViewModel(
        INavigationService navigationService,
        DataContext dataContext) : base(navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
        _dataContext = dataContext;
        _instance = this;
        LoadSensors();
    }

    public DelegateCommand AddSensorCommand => _addSensorCommand ?? (_addSensorCommand = new DelegateCommand(AddSensor));

    public List<SensorItemViewModel> Sensors
    {
        get => _sensors;
        set => SetProperty(ref _sensors, value);
    }

    public static MainPageViewModel GetInstance()
    {
        return _instance;
    }

    private async void AddSensor()
    {
        await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("SensorPage", null);
    }

    public async void LoadSensors()
    {
        try
        {
            var sensors = await _dataContext.Sensors.ToListAsync();

            Sensors = sensors.Select(s => new SensorItemViewModel(_navigationService)
            {
                Id = s.Id,
                ClientId = s.ClientId,
                Name = s.Name,
                Description = s.Description,
                Payload = s.Payload
            }).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "Aceptar");
        }
    }
}
```

## Este es el SensorPageViewModel:

```
    public class SensorPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;
    private readonly DataContext _dataContext;
    private DelegateCommand _addCommand;
    private Sensor _sensor;
    private string _buttonText;

    public SensorPageViewModel(
        INavigationService navigationService,
        DataContext dataContext) : base(navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
        _dataContext = dataContext;
    }

    public DelegateCommand AddCommand => _addCommand ?? (_addCommand = new DelegateCommand(Add));

    public string ButtonText
    {
        get => _buttonText;
        set => SetProperty(ref _buttonText, value);
    }

    public Sensor Sensor
    {
        get => _sensor;
        set => SetProperty(ref _sensor, value);
    }

    public override void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(parameters);

        if (parameters.Count >= 1)
        {
            var parameterSensor = parameters.GetValue<SensorItemViewModel>("Sensor");
            Sensor = new Sensor()
            {
                Id = parameterSensor.Id,
                ClientId = parameterSensor.ClientId,
                Name = parameterSensor.Name,
                Description = parameterSensor.Description,
                Payload = parameterSensor.Payload
            };
            Title = Sensor.Name;
            ButtonText = "Editar";
        }
        else
        {
            Sensor = new Sensor();
            Title = "Nuevo sensor";
            ButtonText = "Salvar";
        }
    }

    private async void Add()
    {
        if (ButtonText == "Editar")
        {
            ButtonText = "Salvar";
            Title = "Editar";

            return;
        }

        try
        {
            if (Title == "Editar")
            {
                _dataContext.Sensors.Update(Sensor);
                await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                Sensor.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                _dataContext.Sensors.Add(Sensor);
                await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "Aceptar");

            return;
        }

        MainPageViewModel.GetInstance().LoadSensors();
        await _navigationService.GoBackAsync();          
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo veo un `List<>` en tu app así que entiendo que con ese rellenas tu `ListView`
Deberias cambiar tu List por `ObservableColletion`, ya que este hereda de `INotifyPropertyChanged` y tiene la capacidad de actualizar los datos en tu `ListView`

```
private ObservableColletion<SensorItemViewModel> _sensors;

public ObservableColletion<SensorItemViewModel> Sensors
{
    get => _sensors;
    set => SetProperty(ref _sensors, value);
}
```

Comment: Hola, no me había dado cuenta en ese detalle. Tienes razón, para que se refresque el `ListView` al actualizar un elemento este tiene que ser de la clase `ObservableCollection`. De todas formas sigue sin funcionar, ahora te respondo con mas detalle. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Revisando el funcionamiento del `_dataContext` y he visto que cuando actualizo un elemento, se me actualiza bien en el `SensorPageViewModel`, pero cuando retorno al `MainPageViewModel` el valor no esta actualizado.

En la depuración se puede ver que el `SensorPageViewModel` al valor esta actualizado (se añade el texto Actualizado en el nombre):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero una vez retornamos a la `MainPageViewModel` vemos que el valor no esta actualizado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En principio el `_dataConetext` es el mismo ya que este esta inyectado en el constructor de cada `Clase`. Lo curioso es que al añadir un nuevo elemento funciona, el problema esta en la edición de un elemento existente. Que en realizad si que lo modifica y lo salva localmente pero no entiendo porque al cambier de `ViewModel` no lo puedo ver (quizás tengo que leerlo localmente).

Gracias,

Answer (score 0):

He realizado un pequeño programa el cual se puede ver el problema que estoy teniendo al editar un elemento de la Base de Datos y posterior mente su guardado.

El problema, como ya he comentado antes, es que actualizado un valor de un elemento del `datacontext` en la view de edición y cuando vuelvo a la `MainView` este no se refleja hasta que realizo un reinicio de la aplicación.

El programa utiliza Entity Framework SQLite Xamarin.Forms y Prism en MVVM

Adjunto el link al GitHub:
[Test actualizar DataContext](https://github.com/BullT/EF_SQLite_Test.git)

Comment: ¿Esta es la solución a tu pregunta?